# Simplify a double integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I'm having trouble with proving that the double integral $$\int_{-1}^1\int_{x^2}^1 f\Big(\frac{y}{x}\Big)\mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}x $$ can be simplified to:
 $$\int_{-1}^1 f(t) \frac{t^2}{2} \mathrm{d}t + \int_{-1}^1 f\Big(\frac{1}{t}\Big) \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{d}t $$

This exercice is part of the section "double integrals in polar coordinates", but I can't see the link.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi sorry just to clarify the integral looks like a product of integrals rather than a true double integral - is the dx meant to be to the right of the dy?

Comment: @MathVandal Yes. My book uses this notation, but I'll edit the question to clarify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that
$$\int_{-1}^1dx \int_{x^2}^1 f\Big(\frac{y}{x}\Big)dy=
\int_{-1}^1dx \int_{x^2}^{|x|} f\Big(\frac{y}{x}\Big)dy +
\int_{-1}^1dx \int_{|x|}^{1} f\Big(\frac{y}{x}\Big)dy.$$
In the first one, let $t=y/x$ then $dxdy=(y/t^2)dtdy$
$$\int_{-1}^1\mathrm{d}x \int_{x^2}^{|x|} f\Big(\frac{y}{x}\Big)dy=\int_{t=-1}^1(1/t^2)f(t)dt \int_{y=0}^{t^2} ydy=\int_{-1}^1 f(t) \frac{t^2}{2} dt.$$
In the second one, let $t=x/y$ then  $dxdy=ydtdy$ and
$$\int_{x=-1}^1dx \int_{y=|x|}^{1} f\Big(\frac{y}{x}\Big)dy=\int_{t=-1}^1f\Big(\frac{1}{t}\Big)dt \int_{y=0}^{1} ydy=\int_{t=-1}^1f\Big(\frac{1}{t}\Big)\frac{1}{2}dt.$$

Comment: Thank you! Great answer!